# Sample and moving rasters between folders

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I've like to sample rasters in a directory and moving to a new one (`train`) and create another with rasters not sampled (`test1`).

For this I make:

```
library(raster)

# Example data
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)

# 10 layers
s <- stack(lapply(1:10, function(i) setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)))))

#Create GeoTIFF for each layer
sl<-1:10
for (i in 1:length(sl)){
writeRaster(s[[i]],filename=paste(sl[i],sep=""),
                  format="GTiff",datatype="FLT4S",overwrite=TRUE)
}

#Imagens crete in batch
f <- list.files(getwd(), pattern = ".tif") 
ras <- lapply(f,raster)


#Sample 80% of images for calibration
rasS<-sample(ras,round(length(ras)*0.8,digits=0))
dir.create("train")
file.copy(list.files(rasS),"train")

Error in list.files(rasS) : invalid 'path' argument

#Not sample images - 20%
rasT<- ras[ras!=rasS]

Error in ras != rasS : comparison of these types is not implemented
In addition: Warning message:
In ras != rasS :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

dir.create("test1")
file.copy(list.files(rasT),"train")
```

I have to problems, first, my `rasS` list is an invalid 'path' argument and != argument doesn't work for not sample raster selection. Any ideas, please!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here `file.copy(list.files(rasS),"train")`. The rasS list object is not a directory and cannot be passed to `list.files`. You are also trying to sample and index incorrectly.

Try something like:

```
( sidx <- sample(1:length(ras), round(length(ras)*0.8,digits=0)) )
  ( rasS <- ras[sidx] )
  ( rasT <- ras[-sidx] )

dir.create("train")

lapply(rasS, FUN=function(x) {
  writeRaster(x, file.path(getwd(),"train", paste0(names(x), ".tif")), )
})
```